# Doing something before program exit

Tags: python, function, exit

How can you have a function or something that will be executed before your program quits? I have a script that will be constantly running in the background, and I need it to save some data to a file before it exits. Is there a standard way of doing this?

Comment: The script shouldn't ever stop, but maybe someone will kill the process or press Ctrl+\ or something.

Answer (score 284, accepted):

Check out the `atexit` module:

http://docs.python.org/library/atexit.html

For example, if I wanted to print a message when my application was terminating:

```
import atexit

def exit_handler():
    print 'My application is ending!'

atexit.register(exit_handler)
```

Just be aware that this works great for normal termination of the script, but it won't get called in all cases (e.g. fatal internal errors).

Comment: Is there any way to make it where it will be called if you press Ctrl+C or Ctrl+\?

Comment: It will be called if you press Ctrl+C.  That simply raises a KeyboardInterrupt exception.

Comment: Oh, I forgot that. And I assume that nothing you can do will be run if somebody kills the python process right?

Comment: @RacecaR: indeed; the point of killing a process is to stop it dead. From the docs: `Note The exit function is not called when the program is killed by a signal, when a Python fatal internal error is detected, or when os._exit() is called`.

Comment: @RacecaR, the only way you can run termination code even if a process badly crashes or is brutally killed is in **another** process, known as a "monitor" or "watchdog", whose only job is to keep an eye on the target process and run the termination code when apropriate.  Of course that requires a very different architecture and has its limitations; if you need such functionality it's best for you to open a different Q on the matter.

Comment: But you can listen to signals, see the signal module.

Comment: @Alex Martelli: your comment deserves to be a separate answer

Comment: @NamGVU It should be.

Comment: @katrielalex Not calling the exit function under any circumstances when the process is killed by a signal, if indeed true, would be very unfortunate: it should be possible to trap and handle in Python code some signals such as SIGTERM (the default signal sent by the `kill` command), SIGQUIT, and under some circumstances even SIGHUP. See [this link](http://programmergamer.blogspot.nl/2013/05/clarification-on-sigint-sigterm-sigkill.html).

Comment: FWIW uses a LIFO (Last In, First Out) system for calling functions.

Comment: Not working in Python 3.9

Answer (score 47):

If you want something to always run, even on errors, use `try: finally:` like this -

```
def main():
    try:
        execute_app()
    finally:
        handle_cleanup()

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

If you want to also handle exceptions you can insert an `except:` before the `finally:`

Comment: Doesn`t work when SIGTERM occurs due to killing of the process.

Answer (score 29):

If you stop the script by raising a `KeyboardInterrupt` (e.g. by pressing Ctrl-C), you can catch that just as a standard exception. You can also catch `SystemExit` in the same way.

```
try:
    ...
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    # clean up
    raise
```

I mention this just so that you know about it; the 'right' way to do this is the `atexit` module mentioned above.

Comment: if you want the script from raising KeyboardInterrupt, why are you calling raise?

Answer (score 8):

This is a version adapted from other answers.
It should work (not fully tested) with graceful exits, kills, and PyCharm stop button (the last one I can confirm).

```
import signal
import atexit


def handle_exit(*args):
    try:
        ... do computation ...
    except BaseException as exception:
        ... handle the exception ...


atexit.register(handle_exit)
signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, handle_exit)
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, handle_exit)
```

Comment: unless handle_exit calls sys.exit or something, then the signal handlers won't cause your program to exit like most people expect it to do when they hit ctrl-c or run the 'kill' command.  See this answer for a solution to that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75732683/13576614

Answer (score 4):

If you have class objects, that exists during the whole lifetime of the program, you can also execute commands from the classes with the `__del__(self)` method:

```
class x:
def __init__(self):
    while True:
        print ("running")
        sleep(1)

def __del__(self):
    print("destructuring")


a = x()
```

this works on normal program end as well if the execution is aborted, for sure there will be some exceptions:

```
running
running
running
running
running
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "x.py", line 14, in <module>
    a = x()
  File "x.py", line 8, in __init__
    sleep(1)
KeyboardInterrupt
destructuring
```

Comment: you should almost never expect a class's del function to get called on your program exits. This is not the proper way to handle at exit program behavior. The behavior is non-deterministic and will not function properly as you expect. [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34983137/del-on-exit-behavior) @Rastefan

Answer (score 3):

This can handle normal exit as well as killing the process with `kill` or `Ctrl+C`:

```
import sys
import atexit
import signal

def exit_handler():
    print("Cleaning up")

def kill_handler(*args):
    sys.exit(0)

atexit.register(exit_handler)
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, kill_handler)
signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, kill_handler)

# MAIN PROGRAM
# for example just reading from the input:
input("Press enter: ")
```

Comment: I like this one.  The kill_handler doesn't have to call exit_handler because handling the signals gives atexit a chance to do its thing.

Comment: Yes, it works equally well when program finishes normally or when it killed with `kill` or `Ctrl+C` (added this to the answer)

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a context manager to do something similar to @Brian C. Lane's answer :

```py
from contextlib import closing


class RunThat:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        pass

    def execute_app(self) -> None:
        print("computation")

    def close(self) -> None:
        print("handle_cleanup")


with closing(RunThat()) as rt:
    rt.execute_app()

# --- which results in
# computation
# handle_cleanup
```