# How to run a command before stopping a python script

Tags: python

I have a python code which start a UDP communication on a port `5002`. So what happens is when I first run the code, it works normally then I close the python script using `ctlr z/ctrl c` and then again run the code it shows me below error:

```
sock.bind(address)
OSError: [Errno 98] Address already in use
```

This may be because the python script is running and keeping the port busy. So it shows me the above error. To resolve this, I thought of running these two commands right before the code kills `sock.close()` to close the socket and `sys.exit()` to exit the python script properly.  Thats why I need to know how can I run these commands right before the code is killed. I cannot use `KeyboardInterrupt` exception because in future this will be running as a service.

I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3850261/doing-something-before-program-exit) but not able to implement it. For example, if I do:

```
import atexit
import time

def exit_handler():
    print("STOPPED")

while True:
    print("Running....")
    time.sleep(1)
    atexit.register(exit_handler)
```

This keeps on running but when I kill the code it doesn't print `Stopped`. How to implement it or is there any alternative way of handling my situation.

Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1112350/5270506

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4205317/capture-keyboardinterrupt-in-python-without-try-except

Comment: @Farhan.K  I do not want to kill the code with keyboard interrupt. There will be a service which will start or stop this code. So cannot use keyboard interrupts

Comment: Ah okay, I thought you meant keyboard interrupts because you mentioned ctlr z/ctrl c in the question

Comment: If you are getting "address already in use", it means that your script is still working (so you didn't kill it actually). If you actually killed it, it would free the resources and the port would be available.

Comment: @BorisSerebrov Yes my script iss running thats why it is showing error. But I do not know why it keeps running when I am pressing `ctrl z/ctrl c` to stop it.

Comment: That's a different question, but if it's still running, then the exit handler will not work - script doesn't actually exit. Also I think `ctrl z` puts the script into backgroud instead of killing it. As for `ctrl c` there might be various reasons why it doesn't kill the script.

Comment: If you really kill a process it can't do any cleanup. You must terminate it in a "nicer" way. You could e.g. open an additional control socket on which you send a command to terminate or, depending on OS, handle a SIGTERM (Un*x-like) or handle the request to stop the service on Windows.

Comment: Yep `ctrl z` sends to background. You can bring it to foreground using `fg` and then kill it using `ctrl c`. Or you can kill it after `ctrl z` using the `kill` command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation of `atexit` module has an important note:

> Note: The functions registered via this module are not called when the program is killed by a signal not handled by Python

That means that if you kill the script without special processing, the registered functions will not be called.

So you should instead register handlers for SIGTERM and SIGINT:

```
signal.signal(SIGTERM, (lambda signum, frame: exit_handler()))
signal.signal(SIGINT, (lambda signum, frame: exit_handler()))
```