# How do I delete a pickle file after I close a python script?

Tags: python, pickle

I am storing files inside a pickle file for later use but how do I delete the pickle file after I close the program? Anyone can help, please? I have in mind using os.remove but where I put it in the code only if after closing a python program the os.remove will be used?

Comment: Yeah, I have seen os.remove and stuff but where do I put it if I want to use it only if I want to close the python program?

Comment: How is your program like? How does it work? Be a little more specific.

Comment: I just need to know how to activate the os.remove after I close the python program

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3850261/doing-something-before-program-exit

Comment: "Ideally", a simple program would have a natural 'return'-termination. In conjunction with (hah!) [with](http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm), this makes it relatively easy to deal with resources. Processes that are terminated abruptly (ie. "clicking the X" on a terminal's window frame) generally have little guarantee of cleanup.. YMMV with the exact OS and mechanism.

Comment: Oh I see, thank you.