# Python - Is there a way to make a function clean up gracefully if the user tries to stop execution midway?

Tags: python

Say I have a class like

```
class Thing():

    def __init__(self):
        self.some_state = False

    def do_stuff(self):
        self.some_state = True
        # do stuff which may take some time - and user may quit here
        self.some_state = False

    def do_other_stuff(self):
        # do stuff which depends on `some_state` being False
```

And I want to make sure that if a user executes this in a notebook by running:

```
thing = Thing()
thing.do_stuff()
```

then presses "stop execution" while running, `some_state` toggles back to `False`. That way `do_other_stuff` will work as intended. Is there a way to do some graceful clean up?

Note: Although my example is quite specific, my question is generally: "Can I do graceful cleanup?"

Comment: How exactly are you executing this code?

Comment: In a notebook. thing_instance.do_stuff(). And actually I use a decorator to do the state toggling. So `do_stuff` is decorated. But `do_other_stuff` is not.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Doing something before program exit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3850261/doing-something-before-program-exit)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Stopping the execution raises the
[`KeyboardInterrupt` exception](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#KeyboardInterrupt), so you need to [handle that exception](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html). But in fact, you probably need to reset `some_state` if the code exits with other exceptions as well. Even if you don't raise exceptions explicitly, they might occur due to a bug in your code or due to running out of memory. So do the cleanup in a [`finally` clause](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#defining-clean-up-actions).

```
    def do_stuff(self):
        self.some_state = True
        try:
            # do stuff which may take some time - and user may quit here
        finally:
            self.some_state = False
```

If many methods require the same cleanup, you can use a [decorator](https://realpython.com/primer-on-python-decorators/) as [illustrated by Tgsmith61591](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63954413).

Comment: All good answers here but this was the most concise. I ended up using `except Exception as e` so that I could then go ahead and raise it after cleaning up.

Comment: @AlexanderSoare `finally` re-raises the exception. It's uncommon to need to catch an exception and re-raise it, mainly it's done when you want to log the exception.

Answer (score 3):

Here's one way you can do this with a decorator:

```py
def graceful_cleanup(f):
    def _inner(*args, **kwargs):
        self = args[0]
        try:
            return f(*args, **kwargs)
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            self.some_state = False
    return _inner


class Thing():
    def __init__(self):
        self.some_state = False
        
    @graceful_cleanup
    def do_stuff(self):
        self.some_state = True
        time.sleep(5)
        self.some_state = False
```

If you try this out you'll see it resets its state:

```py
In [2]: t = Thing()

In [3]: t.do_stuff()
^C
In [4]: t.some_state
Out[4]: False
```

Another cool way to do this is with a context manager:

```py
import contextlib


@contextlib.contextmanager
def patch_attribute(instance, key, value):
    original_value = getattr(instance, key)
    try:
        setattr(instance, key, value)
        yield
    finally:
        setattr(instance, key, original_value)


class Thing():
    def __init__(self):
        self.some_state = False

    def do_stuff(self):
        with patch_attribute(self, "some_state", True):
            assert self.some_state is True
        assert not self.some_state  # show it resets outside the ctx
```

Answer (score 3):

Stopping execution is equivalent to raising `KeyboardInterrupt`. You can [handle this exception](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/executionmodel.html#exceptions) like any other.

Use a `try:`/`finally:` to *always* perform cleanup:

```py
class Thing():
    def __init__(self):
        self.some_state = False

    def do_stuff(self):
        try:
            self.some_state = True
            # do stuff which may take some time - and user may quit here
        finally:
            self.some_state = False
```

If a cleanup pattern is needed often, a [context manager](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#context-managers) can be used to perform pre-defined enter and cleanup actions. For example, if `some_state` is to prevent execution of other code, a `Lock` is appropriate.

```py
import threading

class Thing():
    def __init__(self):
        self.some_lock = threading.Lock()

    def do_stuff(self):
        with self.some_lock:  # prevent doing other stuff while in this block
            # do stuff which may take some time - and user may quit here
```