# Execute a command on python console in windows close session

Tags: python, windows, powershell, session, command

I have to close a Python console that is executing a process, i have to send "Ctrl+c" when the windows session close.

Anybody knows how could make a script for this (Powershell)?

Thanks!

I expected how close the session using a Power Shell Script

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Doing something before program exit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3850261/doing-something-before-program-exit)